# Ember Ajax request doesn't wait for the response

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

Here I'm calling an AJAX request with this "Security.createAuthenticatedAjaxRequest(session, URL)" method and I want to return the response of that request. But, it seems like the response doesn't wait until the request completes. It returns undefined as the response. I think it's because it returns the response before ajax request completes.

```
function minAndMaxGradeAllowedRequest(session) {   
    if (Common.isEmpty(minAndMaxGradeAllowed)) {
        Security.createAuthenticatedAjaxRequest(session,URL)
       .then(function(minAndMaxGradeAllowedResponse) {
            minAndMaxGradeAllowed =minAndMaxGradeAllowedResponse;})
       .fail(function(error) {
            LOGGER('Failed to find Shaywitz Min and Max grades 
            information', error.toString());
       });   
     }   
     return minAndMaxGradeAllowed; 
}
```

This is the method which executes the AJAX request.

```
createAuthenticatedAjaxRequest: function(session, url, config){
    if(Common.isEmpty(config)) {
        config = {};
     }
     return this.createAuthenticatedAjaxRequestWithAcceptHeaderParam(session, url, config, true);
},


createAuthenticatedAjaxRequestWithAcceptHeaderParam: function(session, url, config, isAcceptRequired){
  if(Common.isEmpty(config)) {
    config = {};
  }

  if(Common.isEmpty(config.headers)) {
    config.headers = {};
  }

  config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + session.get('data.authenticated.access_token');
  if(!Common.isEmpty(isAcceptRequired) &&  isAcceptRequired  === true) {
    config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  }

  if(Common.isNotEmpty(session.get('data.authenticated.supportuser'))){
    config.headers['supportuser'] = session.get('data.authenticated.supportuser');
  }

  return Ember.$.ajax(url, config);
},
```

Here is the code where it uses the response of the AJAX request.

```
let minAndMaxGradeAllowed = ShaywitzGradesAllowed.getMinAndMaxGradeAllowed(this.get('session'));
```

I don't have much experience with Ember js. Can someone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: @Phil Sorry for the inconvenience occurred. Now I have edited the question. Could you please recheck on this?

Comment: can you use async/await?